# About jmp and negative address

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't think I fully understand the concept of using jmp instructions to go back in code.

Let's say that at 5Fh in my code I have

```
jmp 9h
```

This will transfer control to 68h (5Fh + 09h), right?

Not let's say that at 5Fh I actually have

```
jmp 0FFFFFFF6h
```

This will transfer control to 56h (5Fh - 09h)?

Comment: Relative addresses use the updated EIP as base, that is the address of the next instruction. Also, `0FFFFFFF6h` is `-10` not `-9`. Otherwise, yeah, that's what happens. Read about [2's complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279520/the-binary-of-opcode-in-assembly/24279592#24279592

Comment: @Andreas so in my example I should have subcontracted 10 (I wanted it to be 9, that slipped) from 61h? (5Fh + 5h for the jmp)? I assume this applies to loop as well.

Comment: You can test things like this using a hex editor and a disassembler. For example, use a hex editor to create a file containing the bytes `E9 09 00 00 00`, then disassemble with `ndisasm -b 32 -o 0x5F foo.bin` (`ndisasm` is the disassembler included with `nasm`) and you'll get `0000005F E909000000  jmp dword 0x6d`  (0x6d is the target address because 0x5F + 5 + 9 == 0x6d).

Comment: Thanks. I think that this answers all my questions and gives me a good starting point.